# Bundle.config issue with jQuery

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have my bundle config setup as so.

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"));
```

It worked at first, but then started to screw up. So I've noticed if I switch out the above code with the code below. It would work for a bit. Then it would break and I would have to switch the code back. Is there a way to fix this so I don't have to switch code everytime?

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-<version>.min.js"));
```

Comment: What are the actual jQuery files in the `Scripts` folder?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think < version > is valid, with angle brackets.

Were you trying to force it to use a specific version of jquery?

Try reset it to the default using {version} with curly brackets:

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
```

Otherwise, give an explicit filename without wildcard that matches the filename in your Scripts directory. Verify it with FireBug or Chrome Dev Console. Not really sure what you mean by broken unless you post error messages.

Comment: yeah sorry. I figured it out and other issues I was having. At work we have an older version of javascript and I was trying to use an earlier version of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this option for it.
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

{version} - Used for any jquery version included.